# How do I print to the console instead of an iPython output cell?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to print my output to the console (the one showing the log information or, better yet, a separate console) rather than an output cell in the iPython web notebook.

This is because I frequently have very long output I like to scroll through, and Chrome lags and breaks on large output, whereas iTerm2 does not.

Comment: OK. What have you tried so far (in code)?

Comment: if your default console is not iPython sys.__stdout__. Better practice would be to use the logging library.

Answer (score 6):

Update of the answer from valhallasw: 
You should use the following, otherwise it returns `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

```
import os
os.write(1, b"text\n")
```

Otherwise, you can also do as Oliver Evans said:

```
import os
os.write(1, "text\n".encode())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write to the console by directly writing to file descriptor 1 (instead of sys.stdout, which is mapped to the iPython notebook):

```py
import os
os.write(1, "text\n")
```

Comment: You can also `sys.__stdout__.write("foo\n")` (`sys.stdout` is mapped to the notebook, `sys.__stdout__` is the 'real' stdout file handle).

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.5; `os.write` requires a bytes-like object. `os.write(1, "text\n".encode())` is sufficient.