# How to print to the launching console of Jupyterlab from a script running in a terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

There is [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31245867/9973879) about how to print to the launching console from a Notebook. There are different solutions based on `os.write` or `sys.__stdout__`, which work fine.

I want to do the same thing, but from a python script that is launched from a terminal in Jupyterlab. When I use the solutions above, the output is redirected to the terminal itself and do not propagate to the launching console.

Why is there a difference in treatment between notebooks and plain scripts, and how to mitigate that?